# using a fragment inside a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I would like to use a fragment class inside a Navigation Drawer.

how can I do ?

activity_main . xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Displaying Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

         />

    <!-- for Drawer -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
         />    

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity .xml :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    //private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // NavigationDrawer title "Nasdaq" in this example
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    //  App title "Navigation Drawer" in this example 
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slider menu items details 
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    //private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;


    Fragment fragment = null ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // getting items of slider from array
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // getting Navigation drawer icons from res 
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Recycle array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();



        // Enable action bar icon_luncher as toggle Home Button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {

                    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                        invalidateOptionsMenu(); //Setting, Refresh and Rate App
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            //  displayView(0);
        }

        fragment = new Fragment5Microsoft();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container_two, fragment).commit();

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //  title/icon
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    //called when invalidateOptionsMenu() invoke 

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if Navigation drawer is opened, hide the action items
        //boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

I would like to add Fragment5Microsoft class to Navigation Drawer. is it possible ?

```
    fragment = new Fragment5Microsoft();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container_two, fragment).commit();
```

my goal :

suppose my Navigation Drawer has a button, I want to click on this button and change the content of my Navigation Drawer .

Comment: so you are using FragmentManager, and what is the prob?

Comment: now how can I set fragment object(from Fragment5Microsoft) to Navigation Drawer ?

Comment: you already did it by commiting your fragment transaction

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/section_fragment"
    android:name="example.ui.SectionFragment"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    />
```